# loop through column with changing cell address

Tags: excel, vba

how do I get a loop to work when I have some cell address's that change and some that don't. (excel,vba)

so I have a piece of code that I want to run through 1 column (BG9:BG500) and I'm not sure how to get the loop function to run through all of the cells and how to write it so it only changes the cell address's that need to change while leaving the ones that need to stay static.

I am definitely a beginner in excel macros and vba so all that I currently know has come from googling how to do and working things out for myself via trial and error so I might not know some of the given things I should know about vba.

this is the code I want to run through the column.

```
If Range("B9") = Range("BT28") Then
Range("BR58:CA58").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("BG9").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

the two cell address's that need to change are the ("B9") and the ("BG9") fore example:
the first run would be 9 then the second one 10 and so on and so forth.
I have tried using this loop function I found online

```
Dim iCell As Range
Dim iRange1 As String
Dim iRange2 As String
Dim rangeName As String

iRange1 = ActiveCell.Address
iRange2 = ActiveCell.Address
rangeName = iRange1 & ":" & iRange2

For Each iCell In Range(rangeName).Cells
```

but to be honest I do not know what is going on here and would appreciate any info / help with this issue
this is my full sub at the minute.

```
Sub IMPORTTOLIST()

Dim iCell As Range
Dim iRange1 As String
Dim iRange2 As String
Dim rangeName As String

iRange1 = ActiveCell.Address
iRange2 = ActiveCell.Address
rangeName = iRange1 & ":" & iRange2

For Each iCell In Range(rangeName).Cells

If Range(iRange1) = Range("BT28") Then
Range("BR58:CA58").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(iRange2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next iCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly, but if you want to change that code:

```
If Range("B9") = Range("BT28") Then
Range("BR58:CA58").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("BG9").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

so that it changes (B9, BG9) to (B10,BG10) and than to (B11, BG11) all the way to (B500, BG500) then maybe that code will satisfy you:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("BG9:BG500")
    If Range("B" & cell.Row) = Range("BT28") Then ActiveSheet.Range("BR58:CA58").Copy cell
Next cell
```

This loops through Range("BG9:BG500") and changes references.
I changed your copy paste method, because in VBA you do not need to select things. In one line you can tell VBA what to copy, and where to paste.
IMO selecting is prone to errors, just not necessary and looks worse. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same row, use the `.Row` from the cell, or you could iterate in a for loop and use `Range("B" & i)` with i being the row's iteration.

```
Sub IMPORTTOLIST()

    Dim iCell As Range, rng As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Range("B9:B500")
    Set rngCopy = Range("BR58:CA58")
    
    For Each iCell In rng.Cells
        If iCell.Value = Range("BT28").Value Then
            rngCopy.Copy Range("BG" & iCell.Row)
        End If
    Next iCell
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use the clipboard, you can use the following one. Probably won't notice a difference in performance but it's optional of course :):

```
Sub IMPORTTOLIST_VALUES()
    Dim iCell As Range, rng As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Range("B9:B500")
    Set rngCopy = Range("BR58:CA58")
    
    For Each iCell In rng.Cells
        If iCell.Value = Range("BT28").Value Then
            Range("BG" & iCell.Row).Resize(, rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
        End If
    Next iCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou for the response, this might take me a while to get my head around, but I will try my best to understand what is going on, the other solution did work, however, I will probably need to learn about icell and loops so this will be helpful for that, thanks again!